# Removing the placeholder images for Product Tags using WooCommerce Predictive Search

Tags: image, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I am using the predictive search to look for products and using PRO it searches for product tags as well, which is great.  However, it still shows the placeholder (like a broken image link box) for the tags.  I am simply wanting to remove the placeholder for tags only.
Anyone have an idea of the 'IF' statement I would use and where I would apply it?  Again, it would only be for the product tags, I still would like the product itself to show the thumbnail images.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress plugins directory open the predictive search folder then open the classes folder. In the file class-wc-predictive-search-filter.php on line 331 you will see a foreach loop

```
foreach ( $search_tags as $item ) {
                    $link_detail = get_term_link($item->slug, 'product_tag');
                    $avatar = WC_Predictive_Search::woops_get_product_cat_thumbnail($item->term_id,64,64);
                    $item_html = '<div class="ajax_search_content"><div class="result_row"><a href="'.$link_detail.'"><span class="rs_avatar">'.$avatar.'</span><div class="rs_content_popup"><span class="rs_name">'.stripslashes( $item->name).'</span><span class="rs_description">'.WC_Predictive_Search::woops_limit_words(strip_tags( str_replace("\n", "", $item->description) ),$text_lenght,'...').'</span></div></a></div></div>';
                    $rs_items['p_tag'] .= $item_html.'[|]'.$link_detail.'[|]'.stripslashes( $item->name)."\n";
                    $end_row--;
                    if ($end_row < 1) break;
                }
            }
        }
```

you will need to remove

```
       <span class="rs_avatar">'.$avatar.'</span>
```

so the foreach loop reads

```
 foreach ( $search_tags as $item ) {
                    $link_detail = get_term_link($item->slug, 'product_tag');
                    $avatar = WC_Predictive_Search::woops_get_product_cat_thumbnail($item->term_id,64,64);
                    $item_html = '<div class="ajax_search_content"><div class="result_row"><a href="'.$link_detail.'"><div class="rs_content_popup"><span class="rs_name">'.stripslashes( $item->name).'</span><span class="rs_description">'.WC_Predictive_Search::woops_limit_words(strip_tags( str_replace("\n", "", $item->description) ),$text_lenght,'...').'</span></div></a></div></div>';
                    $rs_items['p_tag'] .= $item_html.'[|]'.$link_detail.'[|]'.stripslashes( $item->name)."\n";
                    $end_row--;
                    if ($end_row < 1) break;
                }
            }
        }
```